# Why is spring returning me an empty llist?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I dont seem to know why Spring is returning me an empty list enough I have passed in a JSON.stringify() string from reactJS

This is my code for reactJS

```
postData(item){

        console.log(item)

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/addSuspect", {
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": item
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

    uploadFile(event) {
        
        let file
        let file2

        //Check if the movements andsuspected case profiles are uploaded
        if(event.target.files.length !== 2){
            this.setState({error:true, errorMsg:"You need to upload at least 2 files!"})
            return
        }

        //Check if the file is the correct file
        console.log("Files:")
        for (var i=0, l=event.target.files.length; i<l; i++) {
            console.log(event.target.files[i].name);

            if (event.target.files[i].name.includes("_suspected")){
                file = event.target.files[i]
            }
            else if (event.target.files[i].name.includes("_movements")){
                file2 = event.target.files[i]
            }
            else{
                this.setState({error:true, errorMsg:"You have uploaded invalid files! Please rename the files to <filename>_suspected (For suspected cases) or <filename>_movement (For suspected case movement)"})
                return
            }
        }

        //Reads the first file (Suspected profile)
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                // Use reader.result
                const lols = Papa.parse(reader.result, {header: true, skipEmptyLines: true}, )
                
                console.log(lols.data)

                // Posting csv data into db
                // this.postData('"' + JSON.stringify(lols.data) + '"')
                this.postData(JSON.stringify(lols.data))

                // Adds names into dropdown
                this.setState({dataList: ["None", ...lols.data.map(names => names.firstName + " " + names.lastName)]})

                const data = lols.data
                this.setState({suspectCases: data})
            }
            reader.readAsText(file)
        }

        
    }
```

Here is what I get from console.log():

> [{"id":"5","firstName":"Bernadene","lastName":"Earey","email":"bearey4@huffingtonpost.com","gender":"Female","homeLongtitude":"","homeLatitude":"","homeShortaddress":"","homePostalcode":"552209","maritalStatus":"M","phoneNumber":"92568768","company":"Yadel","companyLongtitude":"","companyLatitude":""},{"id":"14","firstName":"Mada","lastName":"Lafaye","email":"mlafayed@gravatar.com","gender":"Female","homeLongtitude":"","homeLatitude":"","homeShortaddress":"","homePostalcode":"447136","maritalStatus":"M","phoneNumber":"85769345","company":"Eare","companyLongtitude":"","companyLatitude":""}]

Below shows the Code in my Spring Controller

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    private final profileMapper profileMapper;


    private final suspectedMapper suspectedMapper;

    public HomeController(@Autowired profileMapper profileMapper, @Autowired suspectedMapper suspectedMapper) {
        this.profileMapper = profileMapper;
        this.suspectedMapper = suspectedMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/listAllPeopleProfiles")
    //Removes the CORS error
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    private Iterable<Peopleprofile> getAllPeopleProfiles (){
        return profileMapper.findAllPeopleProfile();
    }

    @GetMapping("/listAllSuspectedCases")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    private Iterable<Suspected> getAllSuspected(){
        return suspectedMapper.findallSuspected();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addSuspect")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    private void newSuspectedcases(ArrayList<Suspected> unformattedcases){

//        try {
//            final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(unformattedcases);
//
//            System.out.println(obj);
////            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
////            List<Suspected> value = mapper.writeValue(obj, Suspected.class);
//        } catch (JSONException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//

//        Gson gson = new Gson();
//        List<Suspected> suspectedCases = gson.fromJson(unformattedcases, new TypeToken<List<Suspected>>(){}.getType());
        System.out.println(unformattedcases);
//        for (Suspected suspected : suspectedCases){
//            suspectedMapper.addSuspectedCase(suspected);
//        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your method newSuspectedcases PostMapping("/addSuspect") is void, it will never return something.

Comment: In Java http stack, if you want to send response via http you have to print to special writer which you can obtain from HtypResponse object. Printing to stdout won't work. But returning value and letting spring do conversion is generally a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your issue. This is my best guess about what you meant and what you want to happen :

- You want your controller to receive ArrayList < Suspected > as the POST request body
- You want your controller to return ArrayList < Suspected > as the POST response body

If that's the case, try this :

```
[...]
   @PostMapping("/addSuspect")
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
   @ResponseBody
   private ArrayList<Suspected> newSuspectedcases(@RequestBody ArrayList<Suspected> unformattedcases){
        [...]
        System.out.println(unformattedcases);
        [...]
        return unformattedcases;
    }
```

If it's not what you meant, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your controller method is returning `void` and not, if I undestand correctly, the payload that you're trying to send. You have to make your controller method return `List<Suspected>` to receive a body in the response.

Another issue is that you're missing a `@RequestBody` annotation on the param, which tells Spring to get the body from the request and try to deserialize it to a ArrayList of Suspects.

Another thing to note, it is a good practice to use interfaces instead of implementation classes as parameters and return value in your methods. Consider using `List<Suspected>` instead of `ArrayList<Suspected>`

So the final method should look like this:

```
   @PostMapping("/addSuspect")
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
   private List<Suspected> newSuspectedcases(@RequestBody List<Suspected> unformattedcases){
        [...]
        System.out.println(unformattedcases);
        [...]
        return unformattedcases;
    }
```

PS For CORS issues you may want to using a local proxy setup as described in React docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/ And configure CORS for remote environments, without adding localhost:3000.